# Detection Folding Edge(Line)

Tags: rendering, cloth-simulation

I want to detect folding line for the object being cloth modifier applied and render it as mask image. Is there someway to realize it?? Thank you for any help you can provide.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can try to bake Pointiness socket output (if I understood your Q right)

[image]

With *Image texture* **node selected** (and *New* image created), go to *Render Properties Editor > Bake*

[image]